# Migrate Realm 2.x List of Object to Realm 3.x List of String (or other primary type)

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

Realm 3.0 introduces List of primitives types (String, Int, …).

I'd like to migrate old Lists of custom object containing only one property of a primitive type to those simpler lists, but I don't understand how during the Realm migration block.

What I used in Realm 2.0 (simplified):

```
class Map: Object {
  let cities = List<City>()
}

class City: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

  override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["name"]
  }
}
```

What I'd like to use in Realm 3.0:

```
class Map: Object {
  let cities = List<String>()

  override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["cities"]
  }
}
```

How to do the migration? The following doesn't work.

```
if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
  migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Map.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
    newObject!["cities"] = oldObject!["cities"] as! List<String>
  })
}
```

Not sure about the use of `indexedProperties()` as well with those new lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the list of Cities to a list of Strings:

```
if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
  migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Map.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
    newObject!["cities"] = (oldObject!["cities"] as! List<MigrationObject>).value(forKey: "name")
  })
}
```

Indexing `List` properties is not supported.